# Describe the sigma algebra generated by $(-b,-a) \cup (a,b)$

Tags: measure-theory

I've been trying to solve the following question from one of my assignments.

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{R}.$ Determine the  $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the from $(-b,-a) \cup (a,b).$

My intuitive guess is that it would be all Borel sets with $\{0\}$ excluded, however I am unable to provide a concrete proof. Can anyone provide me with a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0\}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra: it's the complement of $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\big((-n,0)\cup(0,n)\big)$. HINT: Look at the intersection of the sets in the $\sigma$-algebra with $[0,\to)$, and note that the sets in the $\sigma$-algebra are all symmetric about $0$.

Comment: M.Scott: Thanks for the hint. I'd try to solve along those lines. But I didn't get what $[0,\rightarrow)$ is. Did you mean $[0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: @Ashok: Yes, they're the same thing; I prefer and habitually use the arrow notation and sometimes forget that students often haven't been exposed to it.